# Matching MD5 hashes using a regex with ^ and $ string delimiters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a function which scrapes MD5 hash out of text. I want to limit the match to only 32 characters consisting of `a-zA-Z0-9`, an MD5 hash value. In some searches, if there is a 32 character match which also has `.exe` at the end of the string, it matches that too, which is not desired. I want to eliminate any matches that include more than 32 characters.

"data" I am testing is:

```
7bf2b57f2a205768755c07f238fb32cc
84c82835a5d21bbcf75a61706d8ab549
95673b0f968c0f55b32204361940d184
95673b0f968c0f55b32204361940d184.exe
```

This is the current code:

```
import re

def md5():
    data = self.text_input.get('1.0', 'end')
    s = re.compile(r'[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}')
    md5_list = s.findall(data)
```

Produces:

```
7bf2b57f2a205768755c07f238fb32cc
84c82835a5d21bbcf75a61706d8ab549
95673b0f968c0f55b32204361940d184
95673b0f968c0f55b32204361940d184.exe (This match is not wanted)
```

However, when I add `^` and `$` for beginning and end of string, it doesn't work. The data input is exactly as above. There is no error, it just doesn't produce any matches, which are there, confirmed by the above code.

```
import re

def md5():
    data = self.text_input.get('1.0', 'end')
    s = re.compile(r'^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$')
    md5_list = s.findall(data)
```

Produces: no output produced, no error code, no exception. How can I match exactly what I want without the `.exe`?

This function lives inside a TKinter application if that makes any difference.

Comment: Please show your inputs, expected matches and output. Thanks.

Comment: Like @ggorlen said, you need to provide a [mre]. We don't know what your input data looks like, so this is hard to answer. Though based on context I would guess you need `re.MULTILINE` turned on.

Comment: You might be looking for some kind of custom boundaries, try whitespace ones, `re.compile(r'(?<!\S)[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}(?!\S)')`. There may be other variations but you need to be more precise with the contexts you want to find matches in.

Comment: I've added some minimal data. I want an MD5 that must be either 32 characters from the start of the line or anywhere in the line, but if there is no whitespace after the 32nd character, I want to ignore the match.

Comment: This is a lot better, but `self.text_input.get('1.0', 'end')` and `def md5():` seems irrelevant. Why not just hardcode in the data as `data = '[your hashes]'` so we can easily run it without confusion? Voting to reopen though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the comments helped, thank you! After some more research, I also found additional requests and requirements based on sources of data I was not made aware of, ...it happens. I needed to find MD5 hash in mixed text, only pull out samples that did not include a file extension and then eliminate any duplicates that appeared in the text. The input is complex, a sample would be this public malware profile
 (https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2017/05/wannacry-malware-profile.html).
 Copy all of the text from this page and dump it into the 'data' variable below, that's your start. The regex as mentioned preivously, needed custom, specific boundaries.
My solution was to use the '\b' word boundary at the start of the regex and specify a white space '\s' at the end, eliminating matches beyond 32 characters. Additionally, I also found mixed case issues, so I changed each matched entry to upper case and then added them to a set. A set does not allow duplicates, so that eliminates any dupes that show up. I now get a clean list of MD5 hash values that checks out correctly every time I have run it. This is easily extended to SHA1 and SHA256 values.

```
def md5():
            data = self.text_input.get('1.0', 'end')
            s = re.compile(r'\b[a-fA-Z0-9]{32}\s')
            md5 = s.findall(data.upper())
            md5_set = set(md5)
            for hash in md5_set:
                self.text_out.insert('end', hash + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the match from the start of the line or anywhere in the line and there has to be a space after the 32nd char, you could use:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}(?= )
```

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}` Match 32 times any of the listed
- `(?= )` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is a space

**Note** If you want to assert a whitespace char instead of a space, you could use `(?=\s)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OXg1Pn/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is as simple as adding `flags=re.M` to your call to `re.compile` so that the `^` and `$` anchors match the start and end of lines as well as the start and end of the string:

```
import re

data = """7bf2b57f2a205768755c07f238fb32cc
84c82835a5d21bbcf75a61706d8ab549
95673b0f968c0f55b32204361940d184
95673b0f968c0f55b32204361940d184.exe"""

regex = re.compile(r'^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$', flags=re.M)
md5_list = regex.findall(data)
print(md5_list)
```

Prints:

```
['7bf2b57f2a205768755c07f238fb32cc', '84c82835a5d21bbcf75a61706d8ab549', '95673b0f968c0f55b32204361940d184']
```